# Wildcard subdomains with .htaccess (Codeigniter)

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter, mod-rewrite, subdomain, wildcard-subdomain

In my current project, I was asked to provide blog feature for every registered user, that means when you register, you can automatically write blogs on site. This was easily done, however, I was instructed to use URLs in format like `http://username.site.com` refering with username to specific user blog.

I am trying to achieve this with .htaccess file, but it seems my conditions are met but I am getting 500 Internal Server Error, wich is caused by infinite loop of rewrites. I would like to avoid that but I can't find suitable solution. Here is my .htaccess so far:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

   Options +FollowSymLinks
   Options +Indexes
   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteBase /

   RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|tinymce|files|css|js|robots\.txt)
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]

   RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www. [NC]
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?([a-z0-9-_]+).dev.example.com [NC]
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/blog/%2/$1 [L]

</IfModule>
```

Additional info: The site is server hosted, but hidden and on `dev.example.com` so blog URL's should look like `username.dev.example.com`, when site will be launched, this will of course be `username.example.com`. It's built with Codeigniter.

Any suggestions about improving that .htaccess would be great, thank you.

Comment: Have you tried removing the first rewrite cond/rule to isolate the issue?

Comment: @Brendan Yes I did, same error.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this is not using .htaccess.

This is what I would do:

1. Create a wildcard DNS record *.example.com
2. Create a blog modal, pick up $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'], explode it and remove your domain. Do the lookup in your DB table.

EDIT:

1. Create a wildcard DNS record, lets say create an CNAME *.example.com > www.example.com
   This way, when I goto kyle.example.com its really loading www.example.com.
2. Create a blog model:

row_count() > 0) {
       $blogInfo = [
        'blog_id'=>123, //  value from db
        'blog_name'=>'Kyles Test Blog',
        ...
       ];
       $this->session->set_userdata($blogInfo);
       return $blogInfo;
      } else {
       return false;    
      }
     }
    }

?>

//  controller

session->userdata('blog_id')) {  //  blog id not saved session
                $this->load->model('blog_model');       //  load the blog model
                $url = str_replace('.example.com', '', strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']));  //  get the current hostname, eg kyle.example.com
                if($url !== 'www') {
                    if($blog_info = $this->blog_model->checkForValidBlog()) {
                        // load your blog
                        redirect('/blog/' . $blog_info['blog_id'] . '/');   
                    } else {
                        show_error('Error - Blog not found', 404);                          
                    }
                }
            } else {
                // load your blog
                redirect('/blog/' . $blog_info['blog_id'] . '/');   
            }
        }

    }
?>

Comment: I have come across this but didn't understand it. If you come to PC or laptop, could you elaborate please? Thank you